# Reference array from class in an other class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, reference

I'm writing a program that converts decimal numbers into binary, octal and hexadecimal. I'm doing each conversion in different class, but i want to use the binary form of the number which is stored in an array(bin[31]) inside the 1st class. Is there a way to use that array in my other classes? My teacher said i should use references, but i don't know how to do it. My files are:

Binary.h

```
#ifndef BINARY_H
#define BINARY_H




class Binary{

public:

    int num_;                               
    static int bin[31];
    int i;
    int x;


    Binary();

        void Set(int temp);                
        int Get();
        void ChangeToBinary();              
        void ChangeToBinaryComplement();    
        void TwoComplement();               
        void PrintBinary();                 

    ~Binary();                              



};
# endif
```

Binary.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Binary.h"
#include "Octal.h"

using namespace std;

Binary::Binary(){

}

    void Binary::Set(int temp){                     
        num_ = temp;
}

    int Binary::Get(){                              
        return num_;
}

    void Binary::ChangeToBinary(){                  

        x = 1;                                      
        for (i=0;i<30;i++){                         
            x*=2;                                   
}

        for (i = 0; i<31;i++){
            if (num_ -x >= 0){                      
                bin[i] = 1;                     
                num_ = num_ -x;                 
}
        else{
            kettes[i] = 0;                          

}           x=x/2;                                      
}
}

    void Binary::ChangeToBinaryComplement(){        

        for (i=0;i<31;i++){                         
            if (bin[i] ==0){
                bin[i] = 1;
}
            else {
                bin[i] = 0;
}
}
}

    void Binary::TwoComplement(){                   
        for(i=30;i>0;i--){                          
            if(bin[i] == 0){                        
                bin[i] = 1;                     
                break;                              
}               else{                                   
                bin[i] = 0;                     
}                                                       
}
}

    void Binary::PrintBinary(){                     
        for (i=0;i<31;i++){                         
            cout << bin[i];
}
        cout << " " << endl;

}

Binary::~Binary()
{

}
```

Octal.h

```
#ifndef OCTAL_H
#define OCTAL_H


class Octal{

private:
    int* oct_ = new int[10];
            int i;
public:

    Octal();
        void ConvertToOctal();
        void PrintOctal();

    ~Octal();
};

#endif
```

Octal.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Binary.h"
#include "Octal.h"

using namespace std;

Octal::Octal()
{

}
    void Octal::ConvertToOctal(){
        int k = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int o = 0;
        for(i=0;i<31;i++){
            if((help[i] ==1) && (k==0)){
                z = z + 4;
                k = k + 1;

}
            else if((help[i] ==1) && (k==1)){
                z = z + 2;
                k = k + 1;

}
            else if((help[i] ==1) && (k==2)){
                z = z + 1;
                k = k + 1;

}
            else{
                k = k + 1;

}
            if(k==3){
                oct_[o]=z;
                z=0;
                k=0;
                o = o + 1;
}
}

}
    void Octal::PrintOctal(){
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            cout << oct_[i];

}
}
Octal::~Octal()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **If you have to use your own classes**

You can add a method inside the `Binary` class that lets you get access to the pointer to the array containing the data. The method would probably look like this:

```
int getData(){
  return bin;
}
```

You can also access the array directly using `Binary::bin`, which will also give you a pointer to the first element of the array.

It would be much better tho if you changed the array type from `int` to `bool` or `char`. If you want to do it even better - use the `vector< bool >` template class. It's basically an array of bools. You can read about it in the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

### **If you just need the funcionality**

You should really just use the standard `manipulators`. There is no real reason to reinvent the wheel. The easiest way to do this is by inputting a number into a stream, and outputing it into a string. Like this:

```
#include<string>     // string
#include<sstream>    // stringstream
#include<iostream>   // cin, cout
#include<iomanip>    // setbase

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int number;
  cin >> number;

  stringstream parser;
  parser << setbase(16) << number;

  string convertedNumber;
  parser >> convertedNumber;

  cout << endl << convertedNumber << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course you can change the base inside the `setbase` manipulator.